# Query Set Annotate with two different query sets

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I'm new to joining two query sets with django orm manipulations. Here is my request. I have two data sets. 1st data set has three columns which are datetime, col1 and 2nd data set has start_date,end_date,week_num. Output data should be weeknum, col1. How can I use django to combine these two models?

First data set:

```
datetime              col1
2018-10-04 08:00:00   10
```

Second data set:

```
start_date            end_date               week_num
2018-10-04 07:00:00   2018-10-11 07:00:00    42
```

Output data set:

```
weeknum              col1
42                    10
```

My code so far:

```
qs1=models.dataset1.objects.all()
qs2=models.dataset2.objects.all()
```

I know I'm just putting in the basic datasets, but I'm unable to move any further.

SQL Query for this would be like:

```
 select weeknum, col1 from datatset1 d1, dataset2 d2 where 
 d1.datettime>d2.start_date and d1.datetime<d2.end_date;
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use querysets to combine since they're designed to be model-specific (w/the exception of proxy and abstract models).

You can however use a list comprehension to combine them or use itertools.chain (more efficient) to combine the two results from the querysets.

However, you'll lose out on the "laziness" of the queryset, which may have performance ramifications later.